# Principal component analysis on a correlation matrix

Tags: r, pca

Many functions can perform Principal Component Analysis (PCA) on raw data in R. By raw data I understand any data frame or matrix whose rows are indexed by observations and whose columns are identified with measurements. Can we carry out PCA on a correlation matrix in R ? Which function can accept a correlation matrix as its input in R ?

Comment: Have a look at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21832254/pca-analysis-using-correlation-matrix-as-input-in-r). `princomp` can take a `covmat` input argument (but it's the covariance matrix not the correlation matrix) instead of the initial dataframe.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, you can use

```
ii <- as.matrix(iris[,1:4])
princomp(covmat=cor(ii))
```

This will give you equivalent results to `princomp(iris,cor=TRUE)` (which is *not* what you want - the latter uses the full data matrix, but returns the value computed when the covariance matrix is converted to a correlation).

---

You can also do all the relevant computations by hand if you have the correlation matrix:

```
cc <- cor(ii)
e1 <- eigen(cc)
```

Standard deviations:

```
sqrt(e1$values)
[1] 1.7083611 0.9560494 0.3830886 0.1439265
```

Proportion of variance:

```
e1$values/sum(e1$values)
[1] 0.729624454 0.228507618 0.036689219 0.005178709
```

You can get the loadings via `e1$vectors`.  Compute the scores (according to [this CV question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/103741/how-to-compute-pca-scores-from-eigendecomposition-of-the-covariance-matrix)) via `as.matrix(iris) %*% e1$vectors)` (this will *not* give numerically identical answers to `princomp()$scores` - the eigenvectors are scaled differently - but it gives equivalent results).

Comment: If use the command res.pca=princomp(covmat=cor(iris)) I can not visualize the results by the factominer package. Namely,  i use the command fviz_pca_ind(res.pca) and I obtain the aswer  "The object res.pca doesn't have the element scores. Please use the function princomp() with the argument scores = TRUE". Hence, I include the argument scores in the princomp function but I still receive this aswer.

Comment: You're trying to visualize the distribution of the scores of a PCA without access to the original data ... what exactly do you want the graph to show you if you don't have the original data ... ??